# ModelMapper: Trying to replace method to mapper

Tags: java, modelmapper

I'm trying to replace this method to ModelMapper

```
List<String> typeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (_strUtil.isNotEmpty(notifyType)) {
            typeList = Arrays.asList(dto.stringToArr().split(","));
        }
```

I want to convert the string "11,21,22,23,31,41,51,52,53,54,55,61,62" to array,
the method above work great but I want that the model mappper will do that.

when I run my code I get an exception.
I'm using http://modelmapper.org/ site but I don't understand how to make the mapper work.

```
ModelMapper modelMapper  = new ModelMapper();

TypeMap<myDto, myDto> typeMap = modelMapper.createTypeMap(myDto.class, NotifyUpgradeQuery.class);

        typeMap.addMapping(myDto::getStringData, myDto::setDataToArray);
        var getArray = typeMap.setPreConverter(context -> {
            context.getSource().getStringData().split(",");
            return context.getDestination();
        });
```

the dto:

```
public class myDto {

    private String stringData;
    private String[] dataToArray;
}
```

Comment: You question is not clear, If I get you correctly you want to map an object of myDto also to an object of myDto but with the value of stringData splitted into an array and save in dataToArray. If this is true, do let me know so I could provide a solution

Comment: I want that the mapper will map the string same like the function.
The dto get the string and I want to split it to array that I want to send to the sql.

Comment: I trying to this with converter but I can't see where is the mapped array